# How do I use a stored Procedure to return a single entity in Entity Framework 4?

Tags: entity-framework-4

New to Entity Framework .Using EF4. I have found articles and managed to use stored procedures to return a list of entities.

But cannot see/work out how you return a single entity.

Given that I have a stored procedure "GetCustomerById" that return a single customer How do I map it?

Using the Model Browser I right click on "Function Import" and I have added my StoredProcedure
however whatever I select does not seem to return a "Single Entity"

Am I missing the obvious?

thanks a lot for any link or suggestions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do *Function Import* you need to select the entity your SP returns from the drop down (i.e. *Customer*). The catch is EF does NOT directly returns *Customer* object as per your selection but [***System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult***](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectresult.aspx) which implements *IEnumerable*. 
To be more specific, here is the generated code for your function:

```
public ObjectResult<Customer> GetCustomerById(Nullable<global::System.Int32> Id)
```

That's because EF has no idea if your SP returns a single record or a list of them so it wraps the result inside *ObjectResult*. You can enumerate through this to get your Customer entity like any other IEnumerable object. For example:

```
Customer myCustomer = context.GetCustomerById(1).First();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.So whether you mapping to a single entity or a list of entities.It will create an IEnumerable and its up to me to get FirstOrDefault.mmmm that sort of make sense.As I work around I created a complex type which I think is wrong.

Comment: No Problem and yes, as of .NET 4.0, EF is capable of materializing the SP's result into your entity, it just wraps it in ObjectResult like I said. When you do Function Import, be sure to select your exact entity and not a complex type.